# Error: Can't update or reinstall my node modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I recently updated my Node and now whenever I try to update the node modules of this project I get errors. This is the only project that gives issues with it, all the other once are fine.

I tried removing the node module's and the react-countdown-clock in the package.json, I also tried copying the files to see if i could find the problem. But with everything I tried I still got the error's. So I was wondering if anyone has any advice for me how to fix it.

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Hi, welcome, take a look here: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Execute below Commands

1. npm install -g npm-check-updates
2. ncu -u
3. npm install
4. npm start

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).